# Unable to get introspy.db file

Tags: android, penetration-testing

I am running Introspy android application for penetration testing of android app but i am unable to get introspy.db file from application's internal files.
I took reference from  https://github.com/iSECPartners/Introspy-Android

Comment: How did you attempt to get it? What didn't work as expected, etc.?

Comment: I installed introspy.core and introspy.config along with cyndia substrate and after running introspy.config app i set to hook only one application installed in device.so according to reference link https://github.com/iSECPartners/Introspy-Android an introspy.db file should be created inside application's  internal file but it is not getting created.I did all this in android rooted device.

Answer (score 1):

I know this was asked a long time ago but in case anyone else who searches needs an answer:

I also had this problem when running Introspy on a Galaxy S4 running KitKat (4.4.2).  I have ran Introspy with zero problems on a Nexus S running JellyBean (4.2.1).  Because of this I believe it is an Android SDK problem with newer versions.

If you look at the AndroidManifest file for Introspy-Android Core, the targetSdkVersion is 18, which denotes Jellybean.  I looked at logcat files and found that I was getting the error:

```
Permission Denial: get/set setting for user asks to run as user -2 but is calling from user 0; this requires android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL
```

I simply added this permission to the Android Core AndroidManifest.xml file as well as the Android Config AndroidManifest.xml with the command:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERACT_ACROSS_USERS_FULL"/>
```

I then just recompiled both binaries and it worked!  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Is Cydia Substrate for Android installed? (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.saurik.substrate&hl=en).  The SuperSU.apk (https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.chainfire.supersu&hl=en) may also be needed to give root permissions to Cydia substrate. Upon installing Cydia Substrate and SuperSU, you can give root permissions to the Substrate application and click on "Link Substrate" button in the Cydia Substrate application.  Then try to start Introspy Config and setup the appropriate methods to hook into.  Hopefully, this should do it. Also, all of this assumes you have a rooted phone or emulator.